# KSQL - Join unequal partitions streams

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How to join unequal number of partition holding streams in KSQL apart from increase the partition ?

Example Stream-1 is having the 3 partitions and Stream-2 is having the 2 partitions . In that case , of course we can increase the number partitions for Stream-1 as 3 join . But I want to know , any other method to join unequal partitioned streams through KSQL ?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately KStream/KSQL doesn't support join for unequal partitioned topics.

It's a pre-requisite that both topics should have same number of partitions before calling join operation otherwise it will fail.

You can read more about Co-partitioning requirement here:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/partition-data.html#partition-data-to-enable-joins

To ensure co-partitioning, you can use PARTITION_BY clause to create new stream :

```
CREATE STREAM topic_rekeyed WITH (PARTITIONS=6) AS SELECT * FROM topic PARTITION BY topic_key;
```

Comment: Thanks for Your response . Can we convert the unequal partitions KSQL KTable to GlobalKTable and join ? That is possible ? Please confirm for the same .

Comment: I am not sure if KSQL supports Global Table as Kafka Streams. But if you are using KStreams, if you can definitely convert to GlobalKTable to avoid co-partitioning.  Just to bring to your notice, GlobalKTable will replicate data from all partitions to each node to join with Streams/Table so it may not be best suited for high volume data.

Comment: Thanks for Your response Once again . As per your statement , I can conclude , Unequal partition streams join should be statisfied following conditions. 1. Both streams should have equal number partitions or 2. We can convert the both streams as GlobalKTable and join ..

Comment: Statement1 is correct, Correction for statment 2 "We can convert the both streams as GlobalKTable and join " - You can't make GlobalKTable-GlobalKTable join.  KStream supports Stream-Table, Table-Table, Stream-Stream and Stream-GlobalKTable join. (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining)  so you can change one stream to GlobalKTable and perform Stream-GlobalKTable join